# How to use Excel VBA to restart a PPT Presentation after pausing it

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have written Excel VBA code that will run a PowerPoint slide show presentation, and the presentation is set to automatically and continually advance to the next slide after a certain amount of time. After the presentation runs for 10 seconds, the code pauses the PowerPoint presentation. All of that code is working exactly as it should. However, I am having difficulty using VBA code to restart the slide show presentation, and I can't figure out why. I did add the "Microsoft PowerPoint 15.0 Object Library" reference.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Code()

Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim pApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim strPresPath As String

strPresPath = "this is where I put the file path"

Set pApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set pFile = pApp.Presentations(strPresPath)
Set pPres = pApp.ActivePresentation
pPres.SlideShowSettings.Run

Wait (10)

pPres.SlideShowWindow.View.State = ppSlideShowPaused

Wait (5)

pPres.SlideShowWindow.View.State = ppSlideShowRunning
```

And this is the code for the "Wait" function that is called:

```
Function Wait(lngSeconds As Long)
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", lngSeconds, Now)
End Function
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I can't get the slide show presentation to restart?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried doing another call to `pPres.SlideShowSettings.Run`?

Comment: Given your code snippet (no logical link to Excel functions), why not use PowerPoint VBA instead of Excel VBA?

Comment: Thank you both for your advice. Thankfully the problem was something simple - I wrote code to end the slideshow immediately after setting it to run again without including a "Wait' in between running the slideshow and ending the slideshow. It works now!